# Read out Datetime from SQLite with C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I create a programm with a sqllite DB where i can save Data (id/date/name).

**DB:**

```
1 - 15.09.2016 00:00:00 - Test
2 - 28.06.2018 00:00:00 - Test2
```

Type: Numeric

I try to read this out with a SQLite Reader.

**Code:**

```
String sql = $"SELECT * FROM test";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Date: {reader["date"]}");
  ...
}
```

**Output:**

```
15,09
28,06
```

If i convert this to Datetime i get only the year 2018:

```
15.09.2018
28.06.2018
```

How can i read out the Datetime in correct format with year ?

Comment: Type are important, You can use a SQLiteDataAdapter. https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter.html

Comment: Try following : reader["date"].ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")

Comment: @jdweng, I thought SQLite don't have DateTime Data type. And we had to parse ISO8601 string.

Comment: SQLListe may not have a datetime but the driver may be converting to a datetime.  It is like Excel using General formatting which attempts to automatically recognize data types.   With Excel it is the driver either Jet Engine or ACE that does the conversion.  The SQLite driver may also be the Jet Engine which is what is really giving the issue.

Comment: Arg I can't test it. but there is a `GetDateTime` on the reader so is should/could works.

Comment: @DragandDrop Numeric. sry forget it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

SQLite don't have DateTime Datatype. You should parse the string ISO8601.

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, myFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

SqliteDataReader got a [`GetDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitedatareader.getdatetime?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0) method.

```
reader.GetDateTime(1).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```